# Compute a list of distinct odd numbers (if one exists), such that their sum is equal to a given number

Tags: prolog, constraints, clpfd

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)). % load constraint library

% [constraint] Compute a list of distinct odd numbers (if one exists), such that their sum is equal to a given number.

odd(Num) :- Num mod 2 #= 1.

sumOfList([],N,N) :- !.
sumOfList([H|T],Counter,N) :-
  NewN #= H + Counter,
  sumOfList(T,NewN,N).

buildOddList(N,InputList,L) :-
  %return list when sum of list is N
  V in 1..N,
  odd(V),
  append(InputList,[V],TempL),
  sumOfList(TempL,0,N)->
    L = TempL;
    buildOddList(N,TempL,L).

computeOddList(N) :-
  buildOddList(N,[],L),
  label(L).
```

This is my code, I can't seem to get the right output, any code critics? :)

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please tag it as such. Thanks!

Comment: Also, what output are you getting (if any)?

Comment: And no, its me trying to learn constraint programming, got it from a textbook though.

I'm getting just True.

Comment: What is your query? Since you only get True something is probably wrong with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can suggest you this solution:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

all_odd([]) :-!.
all_odd([H | T]) :-
 H mod 2 #= 1,
 all_odd(T).

solve(N,L) :-
 N2 is floor(sqrt(N)),
 Len in 1..N2,
 label([Len]),

 length(L, Len),

 L ins 1..N,

 all_different(L),
 all_odd(L),

 sum(L,#=,N),

 label(L),

 % only show sorted sets
 sort(L,L).
```

Example:

```
?- solve(17,L).
L = [17] ;
L = [1, 3, 13] ;
L = [1, 5, 11] ;
L = [1, 7, 9] ;
L = [3, 5, 9] ;
false.
```

Answer (score 3):

Here my take on this question, realized by a predicate `nonNegInt_oddPosSummands/2` and an auxiliary predicate `list_n_sum/3`:

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)).

list_n_sum([],_,0).
list_n_sum([Z|Zs],N,Sum) :-
    Z #>= 1,
    Z #=< N,
    Z mod 2 #= 1,
    Sum  #=  Z + Sum0,
    Sum0 #>= 0,
    list_n_sum(Zs,N,Sum0).

nonNegInt_oddPosSummands(N,List) :-
    length(_,N),
    list_n_sum(List,N,N),
    chain(List,#<),
    labeling([],List).
```

Now on to some queries!

First, "which lists can 19 be decomposed into?":

```
?- nonNegInt_oddPosSummands(19,Zs).
Zs = [19] ;
Zs = [1, 3, 15] ;
Zs = [1, 5, 13] ;
Zs = [1, 7, 11] ;
Zs = [3, 5, 11] ;
Zs = [3, 7, 9] ;
false.
```

Next, a more general query that does not terminate as the solution set is infinite. "Which positive integers `N` can be decomposed into `Zs` if `Zs` has a length of 2?"

```
?- Zs=[_,_], nonNegInt_oddPosSummands(N,Zs).
N = 4,  Zs = [1,3] ;
N = 6,  Zs = [1,5] ;
N = 8,  Zs = [1,7] ;
N = 8,  Zs = [3,5] ;
N = 10, Zs = [1,9] ...
```

Finally, the most general query. Like the one above it does not terminate, as the solution set is infinite. However, it *fairly enumerates* all decompositions and corresponding positive integers.

```
?- nonNegInt_oddPosSummands(N,Zs).
N = 0,  Zs = []      ;
N = 1,  Zs = [1]     ;
N = 3,  Zs = [3]     ;
N = 4,  Zs = [1,3]   ;
N = 5,  Zs = [5]     ;
N = 6,  Zs = [1,5]   ;
N = 7,  Zs = [7]     ;
N = 8,  Zs = [1,7]   ;
N = 8,  Zs = [3,5]   ;
N = 9,  Zs = [9]     ;
N = 9,  Zs = [1,3,5] ;
N = 10, Zs = [1,9] ...
```

Answer (score 1):

I see others have posted complete solutions already. Still, your code can be made to wok with only two slight modifications:

1. `computeOddList` only *tests* whether such a list exists. To know *which list* matches the constraints, just return it. Thus:

   ```
   computeOddList(N, L) :-
       ...
   ```
2. The list `TempL` may currently contain duplicates. Just place `all_different(TempL)` after `append` to fix that.

Now `computeOddList` will return at least one list of distinct odd numbers if it exists. Still, for e.g. `computeOddList(17, L)` it will not return all lists. I don't know clpFD myself, so other than suggesting you compare your code to [Xonix' code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1786365/compute-a-list-of-distinct-odd-numbers-if-one-exists-such-that-their-sum-is-eq/1787303#1787303) I cannot really help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
:- use_module(library(clpfd)). % load constraint library

% [constraint] Compute a list of distinct odd numbers (if one exists), such that their sum is equal to a given number.

odd(Num) :- Num mod 2 #= 1.

sumOfList([],N,N) :- !.
sumOfList([H|T],Counter,N) :-
  NewN #= H + Counter,
  sumOfList(T,NewN,N).

oddList([]) :- !.
oddList([H|T]) :-
  odd(H),
  oddList(T).

computeOddList(N,L) :-
  (L = [];L=[_|_]),
  length(L,V),
  V in 1..N,
  L ins 1..N,
  all_different(L),
  oddList(L),
  sumOfList(L,0,N).
```

I managed to kinda solved it, however it doesn't end properly after it runs out of cases. Hmm.